# angular javascript not working in visual studio 2015 asp.net 5 project when using Bower

Tags: angularjs, bower, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I just started with VS2015 ASP.Net5 using Angular. I get an error when using the angular retrieved by Bower:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TextController' is not a function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=TextController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="TextController">
    <p>{{SomeText}}</p>
    <!--does not work-->
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <!--works-->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js">                              </script>-->    
    <script>
        function TextController($scope) {
            $scope.SomeText = "Go";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

When I use the Angular Google provides it works like a charm.
Below is a what a picture of what was generated using Bower in VS

[image: partial project view]

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
This is the working version thanks to  Claies:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="TextController">
    <p>{{SomeText}}</p>
    <!--does not work-->
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
     <script>
        angular.module('myApp', []).controller('TextController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.SomeText = "Go";
        });
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: this is a breaking change with angular 1.3.x+.  You can no longer declare controllers as global objects like this, you must declare a module and declare the controller as part of the module.  See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149665/why-does-ng-controller-not-work-with-function-this-this-example/29149964#29149964

Comment: as a side note, even though that link to google apis works, I would *never* use angular 1.0.1 for any purpose.

Comment: @Claies this is indeed the case. I you poor this in an Answer I can give you full credit, thanks. Takeaway: don't by deadtree books they are obsolete before they are printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller cannot be global in the latest release of Angular, and, even if it should, you should try to modularise your design anyway.

Declare a module:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

and register the controller onto the module:

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('TextController', function() { /*...*/ })
```

Finally, add the module to the `ng-app` directive:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```