# AngularJS version

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new AngularJs.I working from Oreilly AngularJS book.
I run this code angular version 1.0.8 succesfully but dont running greater angular version.What is the reason of this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div >

    <table ng-controller='AlbumController'>
        <tr ng-repeat="track in album">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{track.name}}</td>
            <td>{{track.duration}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</div>

<script>

    var album = [
        {name:'Southwest Serenade', duration: '2:34'},
        {name:'Northern Light Waltz', duration: '3:21'},
        {name:'Eastern Tango', duration: '17:45'}];

    function AlbumController($scope){
        $scope.album=album;
    }



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Angular 1.0.8 is from 2012, it is 4 years old.  There have been **many** changes to the framework since this release;  It is easy to answer this question and provide the ***currently correct*** syntax, but you really should get up to date training materials, since there will be plenty of other things that won't work the way you expect.

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149665/why-does-ng-controller-not-work-with-function-this-this-example, among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 1.3+  versions you can no longer use global controller declaration on the global scope.
Your controller should be changed like this,

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("AlbumController", function($scope) {

  var album = [{
    name: 'Southwest Serenade',
    duration: '2:34'
  }, {
    name: 'Northern Light Waltz',
    duration: '3:21'
  }, {
    name: 'Eastern Tango',
    duration: '17:45'
  }];
  $scope.album = album;
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/LfnTyxX6Iw3GLcPxRNbf?p=preview)**